# eslint warnings no longer appear in create-react-app terminal

Tags: create-react-app

I updated `react-scripts` in create-react-app and all the eslint warnings that used to display in the terminal when I run `npm start` have disappeared. I know I have code that used to throw warnings, but now I always get the same message no matter what:

```
Compiled successfully!

You can now view annotation in the browser.

  Local:            http://localhost:3000
  On Your Network:  http://10.0.0.110:3000

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use npm run build.
```

I don't have any custom settings (that I know of) so I'm trying to find out how to get the warnings back.

Comment: Do you still remember from (and to) which react-scripts version you updated?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using create-react-app, the configuration of eslint will be in node_modules/eslint-config-react-app/index.js, so take a look how it is inside, usually that will override any .eslintignore or .eslint.jrc that you may have, so go in there and settup the rules that you want to abide.

Answer (score 0):

There were no custom settings for eslint in my app to change or fix as suggested in the other answer. I ended up running create-react-app and copying the code from the original project to the new project. This brought back the warnings I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your package.json is missing eslintConfig:

```
"eslintConfig": {
  "extends": [
    "react-app",
    "react-app/jest"
  ]
}
```

That’s what happened to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can always access the ESLint output window by combining  **Ctrl+Alt+O**. or you can simply click the taskbar at the bottom of the vscode, go to OUTPUT tab, and select ESLint from the dropdown provided.